# Multiline string return statement python

Tags: python, string, return, string-concatenation

I have a short but perhaps not simple question.

How would I format this code to avoid error?

```
def __str__(self):
    return  "\nTeam name is " + 
            self.teamName + 
            "\nTheir regular season record was " + self.record +
            "\nTheir win streak is " + self.winStreak +
            "\nTheir scoring percentage is " +
             self.scoringPercentage +
            "\nTheir average rebounds are " + 
            self.rebounds +
            "\nTheir passing is " + self.passing +
            "\nTheir turnovers are " + self.turnovers
```

The IDLE gave a syntax error.

Comment: Please format properly using the code directive.

Comment: You did not say what error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't see an [fstring](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) example given yet (Python 3.6+):

```
>>> from textwrap import dedent
... 
... 
... class Hmm:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.team_name = 'TEAM'
...         self.record = 'RECORD'
...         self.win_streak = 'WINSTREAK'
...         self.scoring_percentage = 'SCORING_PERCENTAGE'
...         self.passing = 'PASSING'
...         self.rebounds = 'REBOUNDS'
...         self.turnovers = 'TURNOVERS'
... 
...     def __str__(self):
...         return dedent(f"""
...             Team name is {self.team_name}
...             Their regular season record was {self.record}
...             Their win streak is {self.win_streak}
...             Their scoring percentage is {self.scoring_percentage}
...             Their average rebounds are {self.rebounds}
...             Their passing is {self.passing}
...             Their turnovers are {self.turnovers}""")
... 
>>> print(Hmm())

Team name is TEAM
Their regular season record was RECORD
Their win streak is WINSTREAK
Their scoring percentage is SCORING_PERCENTAGE
Their average rebounds are REBOUNDS
Their passing is PASSING
Their turnovers are TURNOVERS
```

Answer (score 2):

We should try to avoid using `+` operator with string as much as we can, since each `+` may create one intermediate string.
Use `"""` (double quote) or `'''` (single quote) for multiline string or use `\` for seperating them.

NOTE: `"""` and `'''` should be used with care otherwise it may print too many spaces in between two lines.

Use format or similar concepts to format the string.

```
def __str__(self):
    return  "Team name is {0}\n"\
            "Their regular season record was {1}\n"\
            "Their win streak is {2}\n"\
            "heir scoring percentage is {3}\n"\
            "Their average rebounds are {4}\n"\
            "Their passing is {5}\n"\
            "Their turnovers are {6}".format( self.teamName,
            self.record, self.winStreak, 
            self.scoringPercentage,self.rebounds,
            self.passing, self.turnovers )
```

Use `"""`

```
def __str__(self):
        return  """Team name is {0}
Their regular season record was {1}
Their win streak is {2}
Their scoring percentage is {3}
Their average rebounds are {4}
Their passing is {5}
Their turnovers are {6}""".format( self.teamName,
self.record, self.winStreak, self.scoringPercentage, self.rebounds,self.passing, self.turnovers )
```

Use format with keyword arguments.

```
def __str__(self):
        return  """Team name is {name}
Their regular season record was {record}
Their win streak is {streak}
Their scoring percentage is {score}
Their average rebounds are {rebounds}
Their passing is {passing}
Their turnovers are {turnovers}""".format( name=self.teamName,
record=self.record, streak=self.winStreak, score=self.scoringPercentage,
rebounds=self.rebounds,passing=self.passing, turnovers=self.turnovers )
```

Use string format style like C/C++.

```
    def __str__(self):
       return  """Team name is %s
Their regular season record was %.2f
Their win streak is %s
Their scoring percentage is %s
Their average rebounds are %s
Their passing is %s
Their turnovers are %s"""%( self.teamName,
   self.record, self.winStreak, self.scoringPercentage, 
   self.rebounds,self.passing, self.turnovers )
```

https://ideone.com/xJ31fN

Comment: Your `"""` example has each line starting with `"` and will be over-indented compared to the original. Also, isn't one of the points of multi-line strings in python to get rid of the newline characters at the end of the lines?

Comment: ["Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation."](http://pep8.org/#maximum-line-length)

Comment: All your triple-quote examples introduce a ton of whitespace and quotation marks into the string that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right. But this is for illustration.

Comment: @SonuKumar "Code without tests is broken by design"

Answer (score 1):

An option that works in Python 2 and 3 is to use the [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function

```
def __str__(self):
    out = ['\nTeam name is ' + self.teamName]
    out.append('Their regular season record was ' + self.record)
    out.append('Their win streak is ' + self.winStreak)
    out.append('Their scoring percentage is ' + self.scoringPercentage)
    out.append('Their average rebounds are ' + self.rebounds)
    out.append('Their passing is ' + self.passing)
    out.append('Their turnovers are ' + self.turnovers)
    return '\n'.join(out)
```